# .Net Core does not support WSHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, .net-core

Moving WSHttpBinding to BasicHttpBinding....

Problem statement: ***WSHttpBinding*** is not supported in .Net core.

When my application was in .Net 4.6, I was using WSHttpBinding to create the connection with WCF with below code.

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var cert = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "Thumprint", true)[0];
result = new MyClient(binding, address);
client = result as ClientBase<TInterface>;                
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
```

Now I am migrating my application to .Net core and i found there is no support to ***WSHttpBinding***.
I am planning to move with ***BasicHttpBinding*** and made the following changes:

```
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
```

With ***BasicHttpBinding*** there is no provision to below code:

```
 binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;//This code is w.r.t. WSHttpBinding.
```

So, my question is: Does this changes okay to go with or I should do some other way around?
Please assist!

Comment: I don't think it works. At present only Wshttpbinding with security=none could be invocated by Basichttpbinding in Core project. Please refer to my privious reply. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54635079/wshttpbinding-workarounds-in-net-core/54664674#54664674

Comment: Yeah!, it won't work. 
I was trying with below federico scamuzzi suggestion but that to didn't work for me.

Comment: I will submit your request as user's voice. thanks. you could also post it on Github issue by yourself. https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wshttpbinding is supported in .net core 3.1.

1. ```
     You should use the Nuget --System.private.serviceModel to get the wshttp binding methods in .NET core 3.1
   ```

[image]

2. ```
     Below are the Nuget Packages that will be required.
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> in .NET Core & .NET 5
>
> **BasicHttpBinding** and **WSHttpBinding**

Solved for me by installing Nuget package `System.ServiceModel.Http` Version 4.8.1

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Http

Run this command in Package Console Manager in Visual Studio

```
Install-Package System.ServiceModel.Http
```

Answer (score 3):

In .Net 5, Wshttpbinding no longer supports SecurityMode Message. Use Transport instead. However, it is not as secure as Message.

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-set-the-security-mode

Answer (score 0):

I did the same (move from FULL .NET FRAMEWORK to .NET CORE PROJECT) and i found `there is NO SUPPORT for WCF` ...

what i have done is:

1 - `Create a .NET STANDARD LIB PROJ` .. with reference to your SOAP endpoint (it support WCF)

2 - `Reference your LIB to a .NET CORE PROJECT`

hope it helps you!!

like:
[image]

and then reference it like:

[image]

Comment: if it helps you remeber to rate it !! ;-) thnx!!

Comment: I am unable to create the binding because of below code is not working.
How to create a binding.
By the way i have created the class library in .net standard 2.0.
     var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);

Comment: in the standard proj add a new connected service (wcf) .. then reference your stardard proj in the .net core proj (on project right click and then add refrence to your dll)

Comment: .net standard does not support the below method i wanted to use in custom binding, while calling the WCF services.
     var securityBindingElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10);