# Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.WS2007FederationHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, .net-core, ws-federation

I'm using library with `netstandard2.0` and `net461` in my *aspnet core* application and while all works good (thanks to *System.ServiceModel.** shims), on some actions I'm getting this error:

`System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.WS2007FederationHttpBinding' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'`

Any way to to make it work?

Comment: WsHttpBinding is not well compatible for Core, so the class library is not valid in Core as well DotNet Standard framework. Please refer to my previous reply.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54635079/wshttpbinding-workarounds-in-net-core/54664674#54664674

Comment: Thank you, looks like we'll switch to OpenID.