# How can we create WS2007HttpBinding in CoreWCF

Tags: binding, wcf-binding, wshttpbinding, corewcf

We have almost 200+ SOAP services written in .NET 4.8 with specified binding as `WS2007HttpBinding` and don't have a scope to modify server level binding. Recently started a POC on consuming 4.8 SOAP services in .NET 6 project. After digging more understood that `CoreWCF` doesnt support `WS2007HttpBinding`.
Could you please guide us how can we create `WS2007HttpBinding` binding in `CoreWCF` so we can consume our `.NET 4.8 SOAP services` in `.NET 6`?

Comment: WS2007HttpBinding is not currently supported for creation in CoreWCF. You can see if the solution of [this binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54635079/wshttpbinding-workarounds-in-net-core) will help you.